# Fallout New Vegas confused about data files

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just bought Fallout New Vegas Ultimate on Steam. I have only ever played Fallout 4 and Fallout 76, so this will be my first dive into New Vegas.

Ultimate comes with all the DLCs, and I'm a little confused as to how they work and what to check/leave unchecked in the data files section of the launch menu.

Should I just check everything and get going?

Comment: Pretty sure you're the one confused and not FNV :p I'd recommend posting a screenshot showing what files you're confused about. IIRC you have one base game file and a few other files the engine recognizes as additional content.